# python: how to check if a value exist in any element of a dict while the values of the dict are lists?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with its values being a list, e.g. `A = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]}`, and I want to check if the value `2` exist in the values of the dictionary. Since `A.values()` will return a list with each element being a list, so doing `2 in A.values()` will always return false. Is there away to solve this without looping over each value?

Comment: Since it is a nested list, you'll have to iterate over the inner lists. So either iterate, or flatten the list and check for membership `2 in chain.from_iterable(A.values())`

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to loop *some* way, either yourself or with built-in functionality. Here's an explicit loop over the values and a "hidden" loop using `in`.

```
any(2 in v for v in A.values())
```

Note this only goes as far as necessary, stops the search as soon as it finds the value. And only takes O(1) space.

Answer (score 1):

one easy was is to flatten the list of values:

```
A = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]}

print(2 in [item for sublist in list(A.values()) for item in sublist])
```

```
True
```

Comment: That `if`  `else` doesn't serve much purpose

Comment: yeah im working on compressing it as we speak, there we go :)

Comment: No problem! Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
A = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]}

for key in A:
    if 2 in A.get(key):
        print(True)
```

You can loop through it by key and check its value by `.get()` function